# Excel Data Conundrum

Tags: excel

Hey I'm wondering if anybody with a better brain would be able to think of a solution for the below please:

I have 900 rows of data like so:

[image]

Which I need to be like so:

[image]

I would do this manually but for 900 rows and 25 columns, it's not really a feasible option.

I appreciate this may not even be possible using standard Excel functions, but I'm so desperate that I'm open to any ideas. Thank you very much in advance for any insight that you can offer me :)

Comment: I cannot think of a formula solution for your issue, but there is definitely a VBA solution if this is an option for you.

Comment: are there only 2 rows and 3 headers per code? Also, if you can paste the sample data as a code snipped so that we don't have to re-type it for testing :] . @VBAPete that seems like an index match formula to me

Comment: Here is an example of the data, unfortunately it's a lot bigger: 

http://image.prntscr.com/image/6b063f9694b04fcb8766b86b26f182f6.png - Sample & Full File: http://www.filedropper.com/techspecs-combined

Thank you.

Comment: All good - thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Advanced filter to get the list of unique codes and put the list in the first column (say starting at `A2` with the first row being the headers).

Put `=match($A2,original_codes_column,0)` in `B2` and drag down.
Put the 25 unique headers in the columns 3-27 (I assume you can do 25 headers by hand).
Put `=IFERROR(INDEX($entire_original_range,$B2+1,MATCH(C$1,INDEX($entire_original_range,$B2,2):INDEX($entire_original_range,$B2,4),0)+1),"")` in `C2` and drag right to 25 columns and down to the end.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this shortly !